# android development if statement with images

Tags: android, imageswitcher

i am trying to create a if statement which checks to see the "ratings" of a restaurant by "-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5". I need to then replace the rating number with a image. I have attempted to do this already but the app keeps crashing, app works fine without the if statement and shows 10 nearest locations as it should. here is the code:

```
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
String name = jo.getString("BusinessName");
String rating = jo.getString("RatingValue");
String address1 = jo.getString("AddressLine1");
String address2 = jo.getString("AddressLine2");
String postcode = jo.getString("PostCode");

ImageSwitcher imageView = null;
if(rating.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating0);
}else if(rating.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating0);
}else if(rating.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating0);
}else{
    //default case, if above all conditions will become false then this will call
}
```

Comment: obviously it will crash because `imageView`  is null. init view with `findViewById(R.id.viewid);`

Comment: Look what Android Studio said about the code you posted: Method invocation 'imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating0)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

In addition to the below code, you need to set up a view factory so that your image can be added to something.

```
ImageSwitcher imageView = new ImageSwitcher(context);
imageView.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            ImageView view = new ImageView(Location_assignment.this);
            return view;
        }
    });
```

Then put your if statement below this code.

---

You image switcher is null. You need to instantiate the image switcher before you can assign an image to it.

```
ImageSwitcher imageView = new ImageSwitcher(context);
```

Comment: oh ok, so in the (context) i would need to change it to rating variable? as its coming up with a error there @Zamereon

Comment: Your context will be whatever the context is at that point. If you are in an activity, just replace it with `this`, if you are in a fragment, replace it with `getActivity()`, etc.

Comment: i am in my main_activity, when i change context to this, it is coming up with a error. the error is: ImageSwitcher (android.content.Context in ImageSwitcher cannot be applied to (android.location.LocationListener) @Zamereon

Comment: update your post with the entire class file. I'm guessing it should be `MainActivity.this`

Comment: check post, 'location_assignment.java' is the entire class file @zamereon

Comment: it would be `new ImageSwitcher(Location_assignment.this)`

Comment: Yes, that isn't showing up a error now but the app is still crashing when i click "get location' to view the 10 locations @zamereon

Comment: @abdul i updated my post. You need to be adding a ViewFactory because the image switcher itself is simply a container. You need to give it an image view child so that it has a place to put the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageSwitcher imageView = null;
```

Its null.

Make it not null.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check 2 things:

First need to initialize imageView (because it's null).
It's what AS said about your code:

> Method invocation 'imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rating0)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Second, is a good idea check if the variable "rating" is not null because its coming from JSON.

Comment: I doubt rating will be null, In case `RatingValue` not found in json then it will throw JSON exception.

Comment: Yeah true, but usually you take care of those kind of problems (console log, build a msg error...) before throw the JSON exception.

Comment: RatingValue is not null. All the results from JSON are fine, its just when i was trying to convert the rating value to a image it was crashing because it was null.

Comment: Ok, it was a suggestion (the second part of the answer) to make your code better :D. Accept the answer better fit your question :)